# Magento 2.1.x EE (Enterprise Edition) - How to enabled and access cms page versioning

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-pages, magento2-enterprise, versioning

Hi i am working on Magento 2.1.x EE and reading the devdocs i got to know magento ee has **cms page versioning functionality**

Where we can **preview/publish** **version wise cms page** and we can also  track the record of cms page versioning content wise as well

I have read this magento offical doc as well - http://docs.magento.com/m2/2.0/ee/user_guide/cms/page-version-control.html

Here they have mention need to enable from store->configuration->cms page in **magento 2.0 **

But i am unable to find this option in **m2 ee 2.1** anybody knows about cms versioning in **m2 ee 2.1.x ?**

Your help will be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: If I remember correctly it has been silently removed

Comment: hmm Yes , It has been silently removed , but modules and files are still there

Comment: In 2.1 they added content staging and disabled content versioning

Comment: @Lorenzo your gave a correct answer, why don't you add this in answers instead of comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento 2.1 they added content staging and silently disabled content versioning.